# CEPH pool img - virsh live attach

Tags: ceph, virsh

I want to attach Ceph rbd block image to running VM.
I can attach img1 by editing vm xml so all works here. But i want to make it live attach.

Pool and image are visible from host lvl

```
# virsh pool-list
 Name                 State      Autostart 
-------------------------------------------
 data-hdd             active     no        
 local                active     yes       
#


# virsh vol-list --details data-hdd
 Name   Path                                Type      Capacity  Allocation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 img1  data-hdd/img1                        network  10.00 GiB   10.00 GiB
#

# virsh attach-disk testvm data-hdd/img1 sdb
error: Failed to attach disk
error: Cannot access storage file 'data-hdd/img1': No such file or directory
```

I was trying to multiple driver/subdriver/type - but no luck

How to attaach CEPH rbd volume to running VM?

Answer (score 0):

here are the correct  steps :

1. create  a block device pool
2. create a block device user, example qemu user  accessing the  "vms" pool :

```
ceph auth get-or-create client.qemu mon 'profile rbd' osd 'profile rbd pool=vms, profile rbd-read-only pool=images' mgr 'profile rbd pool=images'
```

3. on ceph client node, create a block device image  with the quemu user :

```
rbd create foo --size 4096 --image-feature layering [-m {mon-IP}] [-k /path/to/ceph.qemu.keyring] [-p vms]
```

4. on ceph client  map the  image:

```
sudo rbd map foo --name client.admin [-m {mon-IP}] [-k /path/to/ceph.qemu.keyring] [-p vms ]
```

5. create file system:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -m0 /dev/rbd/vms/foo
```

And you can also do a following after steps 1. and 2.  ( direct image also with  qemu ):

example:

```
qemu-img create -f rbd rbd:libvirt-pool/new-libvirt-image 2G
```

and  verify with :

```
rbd -p libvirt-pool ls
```